# How to change permission for file writing inside a directory?

Tags: php, file-permissions

Getting error for this php script

```php
 $savefile = fopen('C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Final\images' ,'w');
        fwrite($savefile, $image);
        fclose($savefile);
```

Error is

> Failed to open stream: Permission denied

But Permission is ok for this directory.

Comment: `images` implies a directory, not a file, and based on your result of `fileperms` that seems to be the case. I'm not really certain why you'd want to to fopen on a directory.

Comment: I want to save a image on that directory.How do i do that.The image is coming from a url.

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `file_put_contents`?

Comment: Otherwise, when you use `fopen` you just need to specify the filename, too. And, per the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), "On the Windows platform, be careful to escape any backslashes used in the path to the file, or use forward slashes"